# Please add a keycap (<kbd>text</kbd>) button on toolbar above keyboard

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It's very time-consuming typing things like `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>` to produce <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. You have to switch the keyboard mode what feels like dozens of times.

It would be nice if there was a button that popped up a modal question, much like the hyperlink button does, to ask what the text on the keycap was, which would then insert the full `<kbd>Text entered</kbd>` sequence with the text-entry cursor positioned just after it.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there is no workaround for this on the iOS app.

---

However, if you need to do this more easily on the web interface, you can use the userscript [`<kbd>` markup shortcuts](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts) by [Brock Adams](https://stackapps.com/users/7653/brock-adams) to get the same functionality.

It adds a KBD button to the toolbar of your editor. Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a way to get that working inside the iOS app?

Comment: @Olathe sorry, I didn't realize that you were using the iOS app. AFAIK, there isn't any easier way to add KBD tags on the mobile app, besides creating a custom keyboard (if that is even possible)

Comment: Oh, no problem.